# Newbie questions concerning CS106A, Eclipse, & ACM Libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, acm-java-libraries

After a while (5ish years) away from programming, I'm trying to follow along with Stanford's CS106A course but my inability to understand how Eclipse is halting my progress. I have looked on this site and elsewhere, but have only been partially successful. Basically, I have embarrassingly basic tech support questions.

First question: the book encourages you to play around with Java in Eclipse, but Stanford pre-loads all the projects. After the Karel portion of the class, I have no idea how create new projects/files/? to do this. How does one create a new project from which one can import the various portions of acm.jar? Whenever I try, either adding acm.jar through the New Java Project wizard or through tweaking the properties on an existing project, the acm.jar icon never appears in the project folder.

Second question: After Karel, I am also having trouble with Stanford's pre-loaded programs. To try and follow along without being able to create new projects (see above), I tried instead to modify MyProgram.java in the ACMStarterProject project. The code is here:

```
import acm.program.*;
public class MyProgram extends ConsoleProgram {
  public void run() {
    println("hello");
  }
}
```

[Here is the relevant portion of the Package Explorer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIwww.png)

[Here is what I think is the relevant portion of the Console tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1StP.png)

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried starting with something simple, like following Lars Vogel's [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse/article.html)? Some of the basics that might be helpful for you are [Section 12 on creating projects](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse/article.html#firstjava) and [Section 26 on using JARs](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse/article.html#classpath).